# Limiting query_posts in Wordpress, but still having pagination

Tags: wordpress

I really hope someone can help me.  Basically I have a Wordpress site I am using as an affiliate site.  I have about 1/2 million posts, which are essentially the products.  The site is running fine, except for on the category pages where there are more than 5,000 posts. If someone was searching for a product they probaby wouldn't go past page 10 in the search results, so What I'd like to do is limit the query_posts results returned to 500 posts.  But still have 25 posts per page.  Does anyone know if this possible?

Comment: 500k Posts? This is quite possibly The largest single WP Instance I have ever Heard of. Quite surprised to hear that it's running at all, actually. What Version do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Wordpress 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

you mean this code

```
 <?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

Comment: Hi ruslyrossi, yeah that was the one, thank you very much.  I didn't realise I could use it for query_posts.  It hasn't made any different to the speed of the query though :(